# postgres python server side cursor won't insert all the data

Tags: python, postgresql, cursor, psycopg2

I have a db with a million row, I want to fetch all the rows and do some operation on them an insert them into another table (newTable).

I figured out I need to use server side cursor, since I can not fetch all data into memory.
and I also figured out I need to use two connections so when I commit I dont loose the cursor that I made.

but now my problem is, it wont put all the records into the newTable as it shows in the log.
in console log I see it tries to insert  500,000 th record into the database

```
560530 inserting 20551581 and 2176511
```

but when I do a count on the created table (while it is doing it) it shows only about 10,000 rows in the new table .

```
select count(*) from newTable;
 count
-------
 10236
```

and when the program finishes, I only have about 11000 records in the new table, while in the records it  shows it tried to insert at least 2 million rows. whats wrong with my code?

```
 def fillMyTable(self):
     try:
             self.con=psycopg2.connect(database='XXXX',user='XXXX',password='XXXX',host='localhost')
             cur=self.con.cursor(name="mycursor")
             cur.arraysize=1000
             cur.itersize=2000

             self.con2=psycopg2.connect(database='XXXX',user='XXXX',password='XXXX',host='localhost')
             cur2=self.con2.cursor()

             q="SELECT id,oldgroups from oldTable;"
             cur.execute(q)
             i=0
             while True:
                     batch= cur.fetchmany()
                     if not batch:
                             break
                     for row in batch:
                             userid=row[0]
                             groupids=self.doSomethingOnGroups(row[1])
                             for groupid in groupids:
                                     # insert only if it does NOT exist
                                     i+=1
                                     print (str(i)+" inserting "+str(userid)+" and "+str(groupid))
                                     q2="INSERT INTO newTable (userid, groupid)  SELECT %s, %s   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (     SELECT %s FROM newTable WHERE groupid = %s);"%(userid,groupid,userid,groupid)
                                     cur2.execute(q2)
                             self.con2.commit()
     except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
             self.writeLog(e)
     finally:
             cur.close()
             self.con2.commit()
             self.con.close()
             self.con2.close()
```

Update : I also noticed it uses lots of my RAM, isnt server side cursor supposed not do that?

> Cpu(s): 15.2%us,  6.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 56.5%id,  2.8%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,
>   18.9%st Mem:   1695220k total,  1680496k used,    14724k free,     3084k buffers Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free, 
>   1395020k cached

Comment: It only inserts if that groupid does not exist. If you show What `doSomethingOnGroups` does it would be possible to suggest a SQL only solution. Much cleaner and faster.

Comment: in my Log it does show insering 500,000th recorde (the print statement) but in the db I dont have more than 11K records... so it has nothing to do with doSomethingOnGroups function

Comment: The print statement always prints while data is inserted `if it does NOT exist`. Your log only shows number of attempted inserts.

Comment: Also - inserting 500 000 one at a time with checks will always be horribly slow compared to the direct SQL query.

Comment: Sure _it has nothing to do with doSomethingOnGroups function_. The real problem is located between your ears. I want to know what that function does just to replicate it in SQL.

Comment: Clodoaldo Neto , the functions gets a CSV column and returns a list in python, and also if any of those values in in the column is more than 9999999 doesnt include them in the list, can you replicate that in SQL ?

Comment: @MedyaGh Postgres can load data from csv with `COPY` comand (or psql `/copy`). And it will be infinitely faster to `COPY` all data from a csv to temp table and then `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` from temp table to a real one.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko the csv is inside a column not inside a file.

Comment: @MedyaGh A single line with values separated by coma in a column? Or a full multi line csv? Can you show an example?

Comment: _can you replicate that in SQL ?_ Sure, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the oldgroups column is in the form `1,3,6,7` this will work:

```
insert into newTable (userid, groupid)
select id, groupid
from (
    select
        id,
        regexp_split_to_table(olgroups, ',') as groupid
    from oldTable
) o
where
    not exists (
        select 1
        from newTable
        where groupid = o.groupid
    )
    and groupid < 10000000
```

But I suspect you want to check for the existence of both groupid and id:

```
insert into newTable (userid, groupid)
select id, groupid
from (
    select
        id,
        regexp_split_to_table(olgroups, ',') as groupid
    from oldTable
) o
where
    not exists (
        select 1
        from newTable
        where groupid = o.groupid and id = o.id
    )
    and groupid < 10000000
```

The `regexp_split_to_table` function will "explode" the `oldgroups` column in rows doing a cross join with the id column.

Comment: thank you so much, what does ") o" mean in the query? (right before "where"

Comment: @MedyaGh Every subquery must have an alias. The `o` is just that. It could be anything, chicken, ship, whatever.